# If $P_n = span\{p_1(x),p_2(x),...,p_k(x)\}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ show that $p_i(a) \neq 0$ for some $i$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $P_n = span\{p_1(x),p_2(x),...,p_k(x)\}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ show that $p_i(a) \neq 0$ for some $i$.

I don't understand how to approach this problem. If I make $k=n$ the set becomes a minimal spanning set. If I have a $f(a) = a_1p_1(x) + ... + a_ip_i(a) + ... + a_np_n(a)$ and $p_i(a)=0$, then my intuition tells me that $f(a)$ can not be represented by that spanning set. Am I on the right track? can someone help formalize this proof?

**Added Attempt:**

Show contrapositive: if $p_i(a) =0$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$ than $P_n \neq span\{p_1(x),p_2(x),...,p_k(x)\}$

Let $f(x) = a \in P_n$ ($a\neq0$) then $f(x) = a_1p_1(x) +...+a_ip_i(x) + ... + p_k(x)$. However, $f(a) = 0$ which is a contradiction.

Is this right?

Comment: I think this is on the right track. It might be easier to formalize your ideas if you prove the equivalent contrapositive: if $p_i(a)=0$ for every $1\le i\le k$, then $\{p_1(x),\dots,p_k(x)\}$ does not span $P_n$. (I assume that $P_n$ is the vector space of all polynomials of degree at most $n$.)

Comment: The point is that if all of the $p_i$ are zero at $a$, then so is every linear combination.  But of course there are polynomials that are not zero on $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is $a\in\Bbb R$ such that every $p_i(a)=0$.  Set $f\equiv 1$. Then $f\in\rm{span}\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}\implies 1=0$.

Comment: I added a proof along these lines. To clarify, since it asks for some $p_i(x)$, it can mean just one element OR all elements? I can choose?

Comment: The negation of $p_i(a)=0$ for all $i$ is that there exists (at least one) $i$ such that $p_i(a)\ne0$.

Comment: Do I need to rule that out or can I just say $a > 0$ ?

Comment: You can just choose $a\ne0$.  I got lost for a second.